# History of Brahmans in Actuality

Tags: history, brahmins

I want to know what the life of typical Brahmins was like in India through primary sources and without text like law books etc. Are there any good biographies of famous Brahmins scholars, teachers, and philosophers from that period? This should be ideally answered in History-StackExchange, but I find that historians are often left-biased and use secondary sources that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Edit the question to *Brahmins*, this word is usually understood as a different thing actually and a lot of people can answer this question better.